# ng-animate is not working with ng-show in angularjs 1.1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate, ng-show

I was testing the animations in latest angularJS version 1.1.5 and it seems like its not working properly. please check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kx4TS/19/)

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app>
     <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
        <input type='button' value='click' ng-click='clicked()' />  
        <div ng-show="foo == true"  class='myDiv' ng-animate="{show: 'fadeIn', hide:'fadeOut'}">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myDiv{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
.fadeIn-setup, .fadeOut-setup {
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear opacity;
  -moz-transition: 1s linear opacity;
  -o-transition: 1s linear opacity;
  transition: 1s linear opacity;
}
.fadeIn-setup{
  opacity:0;
}
.fadeOut-setup{
  opacity:1;
}
.fadeIn-setup.fadeIn-start {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fadeOut-setup.fadeOut-start{
    opacity:0;
}
```

**AngularJS:**

```
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.foo = false;
    $scope.clicked = function(){
       $scope.foo = !($scope.foo);
    }
}
```

However when I switch back to version 1.1.4 it works fine but with another bug which they said it was fixed in v1.1.5. now this is confusing. they have fixed previous bug with a newer one? anyways, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the bug with 1.1.4 that it starts visible? I am seeing the same thing in 1.1.5. No animation, just appears and disappears.

Comment: yeah that bug happens in v1.1.4 now this bug happens in v1.1.5 I'm using the same code btw to show the different results.

Comment: The `1.1.5` has a new documentation: [NgAnimate 1.1.5 Documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate) - [NgAnimate Samples](http://www.nganimate.org)

Answer (score 5):

so after couple of hours digging I found the solution, all of the documentations are outdated and are not updated to the latest API. Here is the solution:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/11f712bc

according to the changes log:

```
The CSS transition classes have changed suffixes. To migrate rename:
.foo-setup {...} to .foo {...} 
.foo-start {...} to .foo-active {...}

or for type: enter, leave, move, show, hide:
.foo-type-setup {...} to .foo-type {...} 
.foo-type-start {...} to .foo-type-active {...}
```

Comment: The `1.1.5` has a new documentation page: [NgAnimate 1.1.5 Documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate)

Comment: My biggest gripe with Angular is that the documentation pages don't keep up with releases, I feel like 10% of the examples don't even work on the page.